# Solr Solarium and Curl throwing an error

Tags: php, curl, solr, solarium

I recently installed Solarium (with Java 8 on Ubuntu 14.04, PHP 5.5).

I created a core called test :

```
 $ sudo -u solr /opt/solr-6.5.1/bin/solr create -c test
```

Then I indexed in it the "techproducts" example :

```
$ bin/post -c test example/exampledocs/*.xml
```

So I then tried to execute a PHP file given as an example with Solarium. In SSH I do :

```
$ php 1.2-basic-select.php
```

And it works, it shows the content indexed.

But, when I open this same PHP file with a browser, I've got an error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Solarium\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'cURL is not available, install it to use the CurlHttp adapter' in /var/www/html/cvrecruteur.com/slr/vendor/solarium/solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Client/Adapter/Curl.php:228
```

Curl and php-curl are installed and up to date so I don't really know what's the deal here.

Answer (score 0):

try to install PHP5 CURL by typing `sudo apt-get install php5-curl`

If you're really sure that `php5-cur` are installed, try to restart your apache instance.